# jQuery Carousel controls locked to bottom of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got a great little carousel slider. Thing is, the controls for `next-slide/prev-slide` only seem to work when the div that they're in is placed below the slider content div in the markup. I would like those controls to sit above the slider content, a bit like this --

```
<h4>Slider</h4><div id="controls" style="float:right;">prev | next</div>
<div id="slider content">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Right now it will only work if I put the controls div under the slider content div.

Now, I can just use CSS to position the controls relatively on the page and push them above the slider content even though they're placed below it in the markup, but that's a problem because it creates a lot of squirly differences in different browsers, as the slider content in the `ul` is quite fluid. I just want to float the controls on the same line as the h4 without having to make the entire controls div leap up over the slider div using relative positioning or the like.

Is there any way perhaps to detach the controls from the 'body' of the slider so that it can work wherever I put the controls div?

```
(function( $ ){

var _css = {};

var methods = {
    //
    // Initialize plugin
    //
    init : function( options ){

        var options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.lemmonSlider.defaults, options );

        return this.each(function(){

            var $slider = $( this ),
                data = $slider.data( 'slider' );

            if ( ! data ){

                var $sliderContainer = $slider.find( options.slider ),
                    $sliderControls = $slider.next().filter( '.controls' ),
                    $items = $sliderContainer.find( options.items ),
                    originalWidth = 1;

                $items.each(function(){ originalWidth += $( this ).outerWidth( true ) });
                $sliderContainer.width( originalWidth );

                // slide to last item
                if ( options.slideToLast ) $sliderContainer.css( 'padding-right', $slider.width() );

                // infinite carousel
                if ( options.infinite ){

                    originalWidth = originalWidth * 3;
                    $sliderContainer.width( originalWidth );

                    $items.clone().addClass( '-after' ).insertAfter( $items.filter(':last') );
                    $items.filter( ':first' ).before( $items.clone().addClass('-before') );

                    $items = $sliderContainer.find( options.items );

                }

                $slider.items = $items;
                $slider.options = options;

                // first item
                //$items.filter( ':first' ).addClass( 'active' );

                // attach events
                $slider.bind( 'nextSlide', function( e, t ){

                    var scroll = $slider.scrollLeft();
                    var x = 0;
                    var slide = 0;

                    $items.each(function( i ){
                        if ( x == 0 && $( this ).position().left > 1 ){
                            x = $( this ).position().left;
                            slide = i;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( x > 0 && $sliderContainer.outerWidth() - scroll - $slider.width() > 0 ){
                        slideTo( e, $slider, scroll+x, slide, 'fast' );
                    } else if ( options.loop ){
                        // return to first
                        slideTo( e, $slider, 0, 0, 'slow' );
                    }

                });
                $slider.bind( 'prevSlide', function( e, t ){

                    var scroll = $slider.scrollLeft();
                    var x = 0;
                    var slide = 0;

                    $items.each(function( i ){
                        if ( $( this ).position().left < 0 ){
                            x = $( this ).position().left;
                            slide = i;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( x ){
                        slideTo( e, $slider, scroll+x, slide, 'fast' )
                    } else if ( options.loop ){
                        // return to last
                        var a = $sliderContainer.outerWidth() - $slider.width();
                        var b = $items.filter( ':last' ).position().left;
                        slide = $items.size() - 1;
                        if ( a > b ){
                            slideTo( e, $slider, b, slide, 'fast' );
                        } else {
                            slideTo( e, $slider, a, slide, 'fast' );
                        }
                    }

                });
                $slider.bind( 'nextPage', function( e, t ){

                    var scroll = $slider.scrollLeft();
                    var w = $slider.width();
                    var x = 0;
                    var slide = 0;

                    $items.each(function( i ){
                        if ( $( this ).position().left < w ){
                            x = $( this ).position().left;
                            slide = i;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( x > 0 && scroll + w < originalWidth ){
                        slideTo( e, $slider, scroll+x, slide, 'slow' );
                    } else if ( options.loop ){
                        // return to first
                        slideTo( e, $slider, 0, 0, 'slow' );
                    }

                });
                $slider.bind( 'prevPage', function( e, t ){

                    var scroll = $slider.scrollLeft();
                    var w = $slider.width();
                    var x = 0;

                    $items.each(function( i ){
                        if ( $( this ).position().left < 1 - w ){
                            x = $( this ).next().position().left;
                            slide = i;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( scroll ){
                        if ( x == 0 ){
                            //$slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : 0 }, 'slow' );
                            slideTo( e, $slider, 0, 0, 'slow' );
                        } else {
                            //$slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : scroll + x }, 'slow' );
                            slideTo( e, $slider, scroll+x, slide, 'slow' );
                        }
                    } else if ( options.loop ) {
                        // return to last
                        var a = $sliderContainer.outerWidth() - $slider.width();
                        var b = $items.filter( ':last' ).position().left;
                        if ( a > b ){
                            $slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : b }, 'slow' );
                        } else {
                            $slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : a }, 'slow' );
                        }
                    }

                });
                $slider.bind( 'slideTo', function( e, i, t ){

                    slideTo(
                        e, $slider,
                        $slider.scrollLeft() + $items.filter( ':eq(' + i +')' ).position().left,
                        i, t );

                });

                // controls
                $sliderControls.find( '.next-slide' ).click(function(){
                    $slider.trigger( 'nextSlide' );
                    return false;
                });
                $sliderControls.find( '.prev-slide' ).click(function(){
                    $slider.trigger( 'prevSlide' );
                    return false;
                });
                $sliderControls.find( '.next-page' ).click(function(){
                    $slider.trigger( 'nextPage' );
                    return false;
                });
                $sliderControls.find( '.prev-page' ).click(function(){
                    $slider.trigger( 'prevPage' );
                    return false;
                });

                //if ( typeof $slider.options.create == 'function' ) $slider.options.create();

                $slider.data( 'slider', {
                    'target'  : $slider,
                    'options' : options
                })

            }

        });

    },
    //
    // Destroy plugin
    //
    destroy : function(){

        return this.each(function(){

            var $slider = $( this ),
                $sliderControls = $slider.next().filter( '.controls' ),
                data = $slider.data( 'slider' );

            $slider.unbind( 'nextSlide' );
            $slider.unbind( 'prevSlide' );
            $slider.unbind( 'nextPage' );
            $slider.unbind( 'prevPage' );
            $slider.unbind( 'slideTo' );

            $sliderControls.find( '.next-slide' ).unbind( 'click' );
            $sliderControls.find( '.prev-slide' ).unbind( 'click' );
            $sliderControls.find( '.next-page' ).unbind( 'click' );
            $sliderControls.find( '.next-page' ).unbind( 'click' );

            $slider.removeData( 'slider' );

        });

    }
    //
    //
    //
}
//
// Private functions
//
function slideTo( e, $slider, x, i, t ){

    $slider.items.filter( 'li:eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' ).siblings( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );

    if ( typeof t == 'undefined' ){
        t = 'fast';
    }
    if ( t ){
        $slider.animate({ 'scrollLeft' : x }, t, function(){
            checkInfinite( $slider );
        });
    } else {
        var time = 0;
        $slider.scrollLeft( x );
        checkInfinite( $slider );
    }

    //if ( typeof $slider.options.slide == 'function' ) $slider.options.slide( e, i, time );

}
function checkInfinite( $slider ){

    var $active = $slider.items.filter( '.active' );
    if ( $active.hasClass( '-before' ) ){

        var i = $active.prevAll().size();
        $active.removeClass( 'active' );
        $active = $slider.items.filter( ':not(.-before):eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' );
        $slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left );

    } else if ( $active.hasClass( '-after' ) ){

        var i = $active.prevAll( '.-after' ).size();
        $active.removeClass( 'active' );
        $active = $slider.items.filter( ':not(.-before):eq(' + i + ')' ).addClass( 'active' );
        $slider.scrollLeft( $slider.scrollLeft() + $active.position().left );

    }

}
//
// Debug
//
function debug( text ){
    $( '#debug span' ).text( text );
}
//
//
//
$.fn.lemmonSlider = function( method ){  

    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ){
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lemmonSlider' );
    }

};
//
//
//
$.fn.lemmonSlider.defaults = {

    'items'       : '> *',
    'loop'        : true,
    'slideToLast' : false,
    'slider'      : '> *:first',
    // since 0.2
    'infinite'    : false

}

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the question, but why you are not using z-index and position:absolute/relative ?

Comment: @SergiyT. If I use relative positioning I get very different placement in different browsers, as the slider content is quite fluid, as I explained in my post.

Comment: can you paste an example code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com)? This would help us a lot in debugging. Thanks.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter. Hi. Thanks. Not sure if this will help you much, I'm new to jsfiddle, but here -- http://jsfiddle.net/R2WTF/ -- shows how those controls sit at the bottom. Moving them to the top in the markup breaks the carousel.

Comment: @spinblade: it's not correct, because you told jsFiddle to use MooTools instead of jQuery :) and you should also put up your images to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) (like `benefit-1.png`, `benefit-cash.png`), and add its address to the source code, and you should also add some CSS codes to make it look the way it looks on your site. AND you shouldn't add `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags here on jsFiddle. AND you shouldn't use `window.onload` when you use jQuery :) there is `$(document).ready(function(){...});` like I'm using it here, updating yours: http://jsfiddle.net/R2WTF/1/

Comment: isn't it this plugin? http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php  EDIT: YES, it is. In this case, why don't you link the original site instead of pasting the whole source code here, without linking to the original source? http://static.lemmonjuice.com/public/plugins/slider/lemmon-slider-0.2.js

Comment: Not sure what you're asking above here, Peter. As I said, I'm not sure how to use that tool, okay?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the line which is forcing you to move the controls to the bottom is this one:

```
$sliderControls = $slider.next().filter( '.controls' ),
```

That is looking for an element immediately following the slider element, then looking for an element with a 'controls' class within said element.

If you want the controls to be immediately above the slider you could try to replace that line with:

```
$sliderControls = $slider.prev().filter( '.controls' ),
```

Comment: Hi, jhummel. Thanks a lot. I actually tried that. It was mentioned in the comments section of the site where I found this script. It didn't work, and I didn't really think about it again. I tried again now and, unfortunately, no go.

Comment: hrm. it looks like you would have to change that line and from what I can tell your html would have to look like: <div><div class='controls'><span class='prev-slide'>Prev</span>|<span class='next-slide'>Next</span></div></div> The extra div surrounding the controls div is necessary because of how they're attempting to traverse the dom. That surrounding div would need to be immediately preceeding the main carousel element.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. Will try this soon. I'm currently hacking things to pieces with what I didn't want to do -- relative positioning. So, I will give this a go soon, as I had to make a lot of changes that I'll have to undo to try it. Thanks again.